# How to combine two different length dataframes with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes like

```
a = pd.DataFrame(
 {
    'Date': ['01-01-1990', '01-01-1991', '01-01-1993'],
    'A': [1,2,3]
 }
)
a = a.set_index('Date')

------------------------------------
            A
Date             
01-01-1990      1
01-01-1991      2
01-01-1993      3
```

and another one

```
b = pd.DataFrame(
 {
    'Date': ['01-01-1990', '01-01-1992', '01-01-1993', '01-01-1994'],
    'B': [4,6,7,8]
 }
)
b = b.set_index('Date')

-------------------------------
            B
Date             
01-01-1990      4
01-01-1992      6
01-01-1993      7
01-01-1994      8
```

here if you notice two dataframes have different lengths (a=3, b=4) with a different `Date` entry in `'01-01-1992'`.

Issue is when I am `concat`ing these dataframes I am getting below result

```
pd.concat([a,b], sort=True)
------------------------------
              A    B
Date                
01-01-1990  1.0  NaN
01-01-1991  2.0  NaN
01-01-1993  3.0  NaN
01-01-1990  NaN  4.0
01-01-1992  NaN  6.0
01-01-1993  NaN  7.0
01-01-1994  NaN  8.0
```

here dates are repeating `01-01-1990` etc. also, there are `Nan` entries. I want to know how can I get rid of `NaN`s and unique dates like

```
              A    B
Date                
01-01-1990  1.0  4.0
01-01-1991  2.0  NaN
01-01-1992  NaN  6.0
01-01-1993  3.0  7.0
01-01-1994  NaN  8.0
```

Comment: Merge is also an option: `a.merge(b, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat` by default concatenate along rows (`axis=0`). You can specify `axis=1` so it concatenate along columns (and join on index):

```
pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)

              A    B
01-01-1990  1.0  4.0
01-01-1991  2.0  NaN
01-01-1993  3.0  7.0
01-01-1992  NaN  6.0
01-01-1994  NaN  8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Or join:

```
a.join(b, how='outer')
```

Or merge:

```
a.merge(b, right_index=True, left_index=True, how='outer')
```